# Pyqt lunch separate Qtapplications in separate process

Tags: multithreading, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, multiprocessing

So what i would like to do is from the main Qt application start a bunch of separate Qt applications each on separate processes ... do their job then report to the main application when finished.

Could you guys point me in the right direction . I tried with multiprocessing but i get stuck initializing the separate Qt applications

Thank you

Something like this ... which is wrong

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui ,QtNetwork
from PyQt4 import QtWebKit
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

class SimpleWin(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SimpleWin, self).__init__(parent)
        self.buton = QtGui.QPushButton("START")
        self.buton.clicked.connect(self.RunJob)
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.buton)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

    def RunJob(self):
    print "RUUN"
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Render,)
        print i
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
class Render(QWebView,multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, prox ):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        # self.crawl()
        self.load(QUrl("http://www.ip-score.com/"))
        self.show()
        self.app.exec_()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    browse = SimpleWin()
    browse.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you show us a _minimal_ program that does some fraction of what you want?  It is easier to help you starting from your own code.

Comment: and the subprocess module http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess might be what you want.

Comment: and a belated welcome to SO!

Comment: You just don't need to create separate `QApplication`s.